# How to query a Custom Object that contains an array as a column in Quickblox

Tags: relationship, quickblox, querying, custom-object

I am using Quickblox API for my application.I have created a Custom Object (which is a table in Quickblox terms) and having some columns. Quickblox allow to create a column of type Array, that can hold any one specific data type like array of strings, array of Integers and so on.

My Question is now, i am having an Array of Strings column in my table and wanted to get all the records in whichever record having my query String matches in the Array.

Example: sat i have four rows and having arrays in each row like this,

1 st row : ["A","B","C","D"]

2 nd row: ["A","B"]

3 rd row: ["Z","B","C"]

4 rt row: ["1","2","3"]

Now i want to get all the rows that contains "A" in the Array in the complete table.How to get it done? is this really possible uisng Quickblox API.if not possible tell me the proper way for doing this using Quickblox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works using the "in" operator. Example:

```
StringsArray[in]=A    returns 1st and 2nd row
StringsArray[in]=A,1  returns 1st, 2nd and 4th row
StringsArray[in]=3,Z  returns 3rd and 4th row
```